# How can i populate a <form:select> with attributes of a List of objects?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to create a page where I can select a name of a player in one field, and on another field the age of the player appears. I wrote the code for selecting names, but its using a List of Strings. Is there a way where i pass in a List variable and on the dropdown I can select the names, and the age box changes accordingly?

The Controller I am using now:

```
public ModelAndView getPlayers(ModelAndView model) {
    List<Player> players = findAllPlayers();
    List<String> playerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for ( Player player : players){
        playerNames.add(player.netName();
    }

    model.addObject("players", playerNames);
    model.setViewName("getPlayer");
    return model;
}
```

The Controller that I would like to use:

```
public ModelAndView getPlayers(ModelAndView model) {

    List<Player> players = findAllPlayers();

    model.addObject("players", players);
    model.setViewName("getPlayer");
    return model;
}
```

the jsp page i have currently for the dropdown:

```
<form:select path="players" name="players" items="${players}" id="players" class="form-control" value="${selectedPlayer}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<form:options>` tag inside your `<form:select>` code.

For example you can do the following:

```
<form:select id="playerNameDropdown" path="playerName">
  <form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
  <form:options items="${players}" itemValue="playerId" itemLabel="playerName"/>
</form:select>
```

For your reference also, see the spring docs for this. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-view-jsp-formtaglib-optionstag

**Edit:** For your age select dropdown requirement, you can use the `onchange` property on your player name `<form:select>` dropdown.

Example:

```
<form:select id="playerNameDropdown" path="playerName" onchange="changeAgeDropdown()">
</form:select>

function changeAgeDropdown() {
   var selectedPlayer = $("#playerNameDropdown").val();
   //Change your second dropdown here.
}
```